# How can I change my connectionString in app.config file at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, config

I created my vb.net project to .exe file.
During installation on another machine, one can change the location of installing package to any drive.
In my project, I have set my **app.config** to point the Database that is available in **c:\project**.
If I suppose, while installation, when I change the location of installation to **d:** or anywhere, I get `invalid access db`. 
What I want is:

I want to reconfigure my **app.config** file automatically, by detecting its current db location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

        Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)          
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("MyProject.Properties.Settings.MyProjectConString").ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\SampleDB;Persist Security Info=True;"
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

Where **`MyProject.Properties.Settings.MyProjectConString`** is the name of your project and connection string.

Comment: I have VS2013 , unfortunately this solution did not work for me

Comment: its not working for .net 2 vs2008 either, says `System.Configuration.Configuration is not defined` even after adding the imports

Comment: Add new reference -> System.Configuration (in .net tab). The ConfigurationManager is defined in another assembly. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: There are 2 system.configuration (one legacy from .NET 1.1 e another one from .NET 2.0).
To save files in protected folder (program files, etc) your application needs admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is too late to answer as the question is very old but I think this might help someone else in the future.

So, there is a way to change the Connection String value in the runtime. Since connection string is a **read-only** item like all other items that are on Application Scope under **My.Settings** so we can't change it using **`My.Setting.ConnectionString = "Something"`**. But here is the code by which you can solve the issue and change any **My.Settings** item that is on Application Scope in the runtime.

So the code is,

```
My.Settings.Item("ConnectionString") = "Something"
```

Answer (score 0):

simple...

```
    MsgBox(My.Settings.Item("remoteAddress").ToString)
    My.Settings.Item("remoteAddress") = "abcserver.servebbs.net"
    My.Settings.Save()
    MsgBox(My.Settings.Item("remoteAddress").ToString)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options: 
1.) Create and use a folder in C:\Databse and set your connection string at design time.

2.)Add the database to the project's data source at design time, then use '|Data Directory|\mydb.mdb' as your connection string.

3.) And if you use sqlserver, you don't need to worry about the location of the database once you have attached the database to sqlserver. You only need to use the proper connection string eg 'Data Source=.; Database = mydb; Integrated Security = False; Username=myusername; Password = mypassword; User Instance = false'.
The above is an example of a sql server with SQL Authentication mode as login, if you use Windows Authentication, set Integrated Security = True and remove both username and password.