# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlComment' to type 'System.Xml.XmlElement'

Tags: xml, vb.net, console-application

I'm trying to update connection string user id and password in the app.config of a console application. I get:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlComment' to type
>   'System.Xml.XmlElement'

with the below code. Words in bold indicate where it throw errors.

```
Dim XmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
 **For Each xElement As XmlElement In XmlDoc.DocumentElement**
     If xElement.Name = "connectionStrings" Then
         Dim conStringBuilder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sConnectionString)
          conStringBuilder.UserID = sNewUserID
           conStringBuilder.Password = sNewPwd
           xElement.FirstChild.Attributes(2).Value = conStringBuilder.ToString()
     End If
 Next

XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
```

Comment: Instead of doing it using xml try editing using the ConfigurationManager. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429477/how-can-i-change-my-app-config-files-connection-string-at-runtime

Comment: I just want to change the user id and password @@

Comment: These aren't xml fields so you'll need to do a string replacement. I'd recommend using Regex.Replace for this. So grab the existing connection string, transform it, then write it back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type check before using Name property on XmlElement. I think below code should server your purpose:

**VB .Net:**

```
For Each element In XmlDoc.DocumentElement
    If element.GetType.Equals(GetType(System.Xml.XmlElement)) Then //Type check first
        Dim xElement As XmlElement = CType(element,XmlElement) //Then convert to XmlElement
        If (xElement.Name = "connectionStrings") Then
            Dim conStringBuilder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sConnectionString)
            conStringBuilder.UserID = sNewUserID
            conStringBuilder.Password = sNewPwd
            xElement.FirstChild.Attributes(2).Value = conStringBuilder.ToString
        End If            
    End If        
Next
```

**C#:**

```
    foreach (var element in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
    {
        if (element.GetType().Equals(typeof(System.Xml.XmlElement)))  //Type check first
        {
            XmlElement xElement = (XmlElement)element;   //Then convert to XmlElement

            if ((xElement.Name == "connectionStrings"))
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder conStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sConnectionString);
                conStringBuilder.UserID = sNewUserID;
                conStringBuilder.Password = sNewPwd;
                xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[2].Value = conStringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
foreach (XmlLinkedNode xe in xn.ChildNodes){
  if (xe.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment){

  }
}
```